# Best way to code my unintelligent Nim game?

Tags: java

This is my nim game (goal is dont be the last person to pick up marbles), can someone please guide me. In playing the game, I have just one question

1. How can I keep track of whose turn it is, I guess if I can keep track of that I can monitor my remainingMarbles. This is the crux of my code. Please help

   ```
   public class Nim{
      public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    System.out.println("************** Welcome to the game of Nim *******************");
    System.out.println("The object of this game is to make me take the last marble off the table");
    System.out.println("You must take at least 1 and you can take up to 3 marbles on your turn");
    System.out.println("You can go first");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int MARBLES = 13;
    int remainingMarbles;
    String input;
    do {
        //boolean whoseTurn = true;
        remainingMarbles = MARBLES;
        System.out.println("There are " + MARBLES + " marbles on the table");
        while (remainingMarbles > 0){
            remainingMarbles -= getUserSelection();
            System.out.println("There are " + (remainingMarbles -= getComputerSelection()) + " marble(s) on the table.");
        }
        if (1 <= remainingMarbles && remainingMarbles <= 2 && remainingMarbles < 0) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! you won!");
            System.out.println("Want to play again? y/n");
            input = scan.nextLine();
            input = input.toLowerCase();
        } else
            System.out.println("Hard luck you lose!");
            System.out.println("Want to play again? y/n");
            input = scan.nextLine();
            input = input.toLowerCase();
    }while (input.charAt(0) == 'y');
   }

   private static int getUserSelection()
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter 1, 2 or 3");
        int userSelection = scan.nextInt();
        if (isValidMove(userSelection)){
            return userSelection;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not a valid entry");
        }
    }while (true);
    }

    private static boolean isValidMove(int input)
    {
       return 1 <= input && input <= 3;
    }

   private static int getComputerSelection ()
   {
      Random generator = new Random();
      int computerSelection = 1 + generator.nextInt(3);
      System.out.println("The computer chooses " + computerSelection);
      return computerSelection;
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a `boolean` before the loop.

```
boolean whoseTurn = true;
```

When the variable is `true` it's the first player's turn, otherwise the second player's turn.

Now inside the while loop we change the variable at the end of every repetition:

```
whoseTurn = !whoseTurn;
```

(Which is a faster way of this)

```
if(whoseTurn) whoseTurn = false;
else whoseTurn = true;
```

To conclude, you should do something like that:

```
...
boolean whoseTurn = true;
while(remainingMarbles > 0){
    remainingMarbles -= getUserSelection();
    System.out.println("There are " + (remainingMarbles -= getComputerSelection()) + " marble(s) on the table.");
    whoseTurn = !whoseTurn;
}
...
```

Comment: The variable naming is unobvious.   Without looking at the code, you can't tell whose turn it is if `whoseTurn` is `true`.  If you want to use a boolean, it should be named like 'userTurn' or 'computerTurn' .  (I know this name came from the OP, not the answer).

Comment: I have updated according but I get into a situation where the computer picks less than what's left. How can I fix this

Comment: p
        while (remainingMarbles > 0) {
            while (remainingMarbles > 0) {
                remainingMarbles -= getUserSelection();
                userTurn = !userTurn;
                System.out.println("There are " + (remainingMarbles -= Math.min(getComputerSelection(), remainingMarbles)) + " marbles on the table");
                userTurn = userTurn;
            }
        }
        if (userTurn){
            System.out.println("Congratulations! you won!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hard luck you lose!");
        }
    }

Comment: @the_brass_bottle This question has spiralled a bit and you should make an another post for this question.